# Python Invert Arbitrary Data of Any Type

Tags: python

Long story short. I have an external device storing data. This device stores the data twice, once normally, and once with all the bits inverted (0b1011 would also be stored as 0b0100 on an adjacent drive). It does this for whatever data you give it. Regardless of the type.

Now, there is already an existing external method i can not modify that will get this data. If it is a int it gets it as an int, a float it gets it as a float, a string it gets it as a string, ect...

I am currently trying to write a method that, once we have the data, verifies that the data is the same both inverted, and non inverted. Some pseudo code for that is below.

```py
def get_tag_values(
    tag_name: str,
    primary_ch: Channel,
) -> Tuple[Any, Any]:
    tag = TagChecker(tag_name)
    normal_value = tag.get()
    with debug_mode(channel):
        diagnostic_value = tag.get()
    return normal_value, diagnostics value

def verify_tag_values(
    tag_name: str,
    primary_ch: Channel,
    expected_value: Optional[Any] = None,
) -> bool:
    primary_normal, primary_diag = get_tag_values(tag_name, primary_ch)
    return primary_normal == ~primary_diag
```

The issue with this pseudo code, however, is that in python ~ does not work on all types. This is a problem for my verification because the return value from the getter can be any type. Which leads me to my questions.

1. Is there a method in python that I can just pass arbitrary data of an arbitrary type and get it back with all the bits flipped?
2. Is there a method in python to cast any arbitrary data of arbitrary type to a raw binary value/raw bytes that I can then invert/perform bitwise operands on?

Answer (score 0):

Python has [bytearray](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/bytearray), which does what I assume you need. It will convert what's passed to it into an array of bytes, which can then be inverted by XORing them with a bitmask consisting of all 1s, like so:

```py
import struct
def verify_tag_value(
    tag_name: str,
    primary_ch: Channel,
    expected_value: Optional[Any] = None,
) -> bool:
    primary_normal, primary_diag = get_tag_values(tag_name, primary_ch)
    if (isinstance(primary_normal, float)):
        normal_barray = bytearray(struct.pack('f', primary_normal))
    else:
        normal_barray = bytearray(primary_normal)
    if (isinstance(primary_diag, float)):
        diag_barray = bytearray(struct.pack('f', primary_diag))
    else: 
        diag_barray = bytearray(primary_diag)
    diag_barray = bytearray(primary_diag)
    diag_barray ^= 0b11111111 #NOTs the diag
    return normal_barray == diag_barray
```

Comment: bytearray doesnt appear to work if the getter returns a float.

Comment: That is true, Falderol, I forgot to consider that. Looking at your problem a lot more closely, it is unfortunate that the method this data is fetched isn't modifiable. It would be much for this purpose easier to read in the data on the device as binary "files" and invert that way. However given that the data is being changed to python types, you may have to simply treat floats differently. I'll edit my answer in a moment.